# How to make option selected?

Tags: msdropdown

I'm trying to set value for dropdown after some Ajax call.

I have tried with below to set option value.

```
oDropdown.set("selectedIndex", 2);
```

Though the value is selected in hidden original select box but not showing on msDropDown select box.

Anyone know how to select option after Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see the elements

```
oDropdown.refresh();
```

And before:

```
oDropdown.set("selectedIndex", 2);
```

Resolve your problem? :P